# Adding a new ActiveMerchant Gateway (Elavon) to Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm attempting to implement a new payment gateway for Spree, one that is supported in ActiveMerchant (Elavon). On Spree's website, it seems very trivial to do, but it seems there's a step that I'm missing. I've written a model in /app/model/gateways/elavon.rb

```
class Gateway::Elavon < Gateway
      preference :login, :string
      preference :password, :string
      preference :user, :string
      def provider_class
        ActiveMerchant::Billing::ElavonGateway
      end
   end
end
```

I'm guessing I'm missing some way to load this gateway on startup? I also believe I need to set a specific setting for spree when it loads, and can't seem to get that working either.

```
Spree::Config.set( :auto_capture, true )
```

I've tried placing it in config/application.rb, but to no avail.

I've even tried using just this gem:
    https://github.com/baracek/spree_elavon_gateway

When I try to startup spree, I get the error:

```
/home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bundler/gems/spree_elavon_gateway-802ab1e3bf31/app/models/gateway/elavon.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': wrong argument type Module (expected Class) (TypeError)
```

Any help or pointers is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any success? I've created my own gateway but using activemerchant, now I need to integrate this new payment with my spree and I'm lost.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should be like: -

also make sure you have added the spree_gateway gem in your gemfile.

```
module Spree
  class Gateway::Elavon < Gateway
    preference :login, :string
    preference :password, :string
    preference :user, :string

    def provider_class
      ActiveMerchant::Billing::ElavonGateway
    end
  end
end
```

re reading your error it could also be that the capital M in module is causing the error you can also try changing Module to module

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest fixing the `spree_elavon_gateway` gem in a fork and sending a pull request to the official repository on GitHub. Meanwhile, you can use your branch of it just fine :). I'm actually planning on using `spree_elavon_gateway` very soon, so I may fix it myself if you don't.

Comment: I liked this line
> `so I may fix it myself if you don't`

Comment: @illusionist ha, ironically I never ended up fixing it. The project I was working on fell through. I did, however, port it to Spree 1.1 at the time: https://github.com/sfsekaran/spree_elavon_gateway/commits/port_to_1.1.x